# Grails 3 : ServletContext is coming null in grails service

Tags: grails, grails-3.3, grails-services

I am unable to get servletcontext while calling 1 service method from another.

And if i move that called code to calling service class then its working fine.

CreditFilesService
[CreditFilesService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjSCd.png)

LakshyaUtilsService
[LakshyaUtilsService Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyU2E.png)

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'configuration' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
    at com.lakshya.LakshyaUtilsService.uploadFilesToAWS(LakshyaUtilsService.groovy:3074)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at com.lakshya.credit.CreditFilesService.generateZipFile(CreditFilesService.groovy:110)
    at com.lakshya.credit.CreditFilesService$generateZipFile.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)`

Comment: show your code from LakshyaUtilsService.groovy around line 3074

Comment: How is servletContext accessed or injected in LakshyaUtilsService and CreditFilesService?

Comment: Adding comment for the same.

Comment: Daniel it was done using def servletContext only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused due to issue in code

**Grails 2** was able to call private method from one service to another service with all internal injections being done properly.

While in **Grails 3.3.3/3.3.4** it was calling the private method but the injections was not happening. so this issue was coming.